# Wordpress: Change robots meta tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I was wondering, is there any way to override the robots meta tag that Wordpress is placing with the wp_head() function. For some reason I can't uncheck the box that says "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" (when I uncheck the box, and save the settings, the page reloads and the box is checked again).

I've found the function that places the meta tag in the wp_includes folder, but I don't want to change anything in the core so I was wondering if it's possible to do it in any other way.

Thanks!

Edit: I tried disabling all my plugins, that didn't solve the checkbox issue.

Comment: Depends on the theme you're using. Once you know what theme you're using you'll likely find a `header.php` in that theme's directory `wp-content/themes/yourThemeName`

Comment: I'm using a custom made theme. The problem is that the meta tag is placed with the wp_head() function, it's not in the header.php itself. The html for the meta tag is in wp-includes/general-template.php, but I'd rather not change it there (as my adjustments will be removed when Wordpress is updated (I think) ).

Answer (score 3):

Use a wordpress plugin called [head-cleaner](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/head-cleaner/), it lets you edit the output of the `wp_head()` function.

> Cleaning tags from your WordPress header and footer.

---

To edit it manually, open `wp-includes/general-template.php`
and search for function `wp_head`

Comment: I installed Head Cleaner, but I couldn't find any option to edit the robots meta tag. I ended up editing my general-template.php, but it's not really a permanent solution.

Comment: It will work, until you find a permanent solution, maybe you can create you own plugin! GL

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of your plugins are overrirding the normal behaviour.I would disable all ,no necesary, plugins and see what happens when you disable that checkbox.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it in my post. I disabled all my plug-ins, and I still couldn't uncheck it..